# How do I embed fonts that defined in "SVG format" in a SVG file after the death of <glyph>?

Tags: svg

Here is the code. Exported from Adobe Animate CC.

Now according to the [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/glyph). It's Deprecated.

I found some post like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43841049/what-is-the-new-syntax-for-svg-fonts) but still couldn't figure out how do I make it working in the following way:

- Keep the font detail in SVG format, not an external URI.

here is the code:
(I ignored the `4`~`9` and `.` in the code because StackOverflow won't let me insert too much code)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="0px" y="0px" width="1280px" height="720px" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">
<defs>
<font horiz-adv-x="2048">
<!--  Font Name: Rockwell
Vendor ID: MONO
© 2014 The Monotype Corporation. All Rights Reserved.
URL for more Information: http://www.adobe.com/go/font_vendor_id?ID=MONO&Name=Rockwell&PSName=Rockwell-Regular&applanguage=en_US-->
<font-face font-family="Rockwell_Regular" units-per-em="2048" ascent="1391" descent="657"/>

<glyph unicode="0" horiz-adv-x="1202" d="
M 375 294
Q 299 436 299 752 299 1053 372 1204 444 1356 600 1356 745 1356 824 1220 903 1085 903 760 903 432 827 292 750 152 602 152 451 152 375 294 Z
M 987 1323
Q 852 1532 602 1532 442 1532 324 1441 205 1350 142 1174 78 999 78 752 78 395 213 185 348 -25 602 -25 762 -25 879 65 995 156 1059 331 1122 506 1122 752 1122 1114 987 1323 Z"/>

<glyph unicode="1" horiz-adv-x="1202" d="
M 733 184
L 733 1505 319 1505 319 1325 526 1325 526 184 319 184 319 0 928 0 928 184 733 184 Z"/>

<glyph unicode="2" horiz-adv-x="1202" d="
M 1003 1324
Q 952 1417 850 1474 748 1532 596 1532 473 1532 385 1495 297 1458 233 1380 127 1245 127 1004
L 127 946 326 946 326 997
Q 326 1180 384 1267 442 1354 590 1354 705 1354 771 1290 836 1227 836 1114 836 1034 795 971 754 909 651 834
L 502 721
Q 383 631 298 543 213 455 152 319 90 184 88 0
L 1053 0 1065 539 883 539 874 190 307 190
Q 324 274 370 342 416 410 481 466
L 664 612 760 684
Q 924 805 989 900 1053 995 1053 1122 1053 1231 1003 1324 Z"/>

</defs>

<g transform="matrix( 1, 0, 0, 1, 335,278.25) ">
<clipPath id="Mask_Mask_1">
<rect x="-2" y="-2" width="152.25" height="28" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="none"/>
</clipPath>

<text clip-path="url(#Mask_Mask_1)" writing-mode="lr"><tspan x="0" y="16.3" baseline-shift="0%" kerning="auto" font-family="Rockwell_Regular" font-size="24" fill="#660000" xml:space="preserve">0123456789.</tspan></text>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: You don't, you convert them to something that is not dead. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278707/how-to-convert-svg-files-to-a-font

Comment: You can still keep font data in your svg, but to do so the glyphs will need to be converted to a supported font type, then encoded and embedded.

Comment: Any example for this? @whydoubt